# How to change background image in js file but not hard coding url

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I cannot figure out why I can't change background images when I use `onmouseover` events. My goal is when I put mouse over first pic, then this pic will show up on the top of page, when I move my mouse to another pic, then this new pic will show up on the top instead, then when I move mouse to the third pic, the third pic will show up on the top. Here I attached my html code and js code. Please help me.

```js
function upDate(previewPic){
    // document.getElementById("image").style.backgroundColor = "green";
    document.getElementById("image").style.backgroundColor = "url(previewPic.src)";
    document.getElementById("image").innerHTML = previewPic.alt + ".  this is onmouseover events";
}

function unDo(){
    document.getElementById("image").style.backgroundColor = "#8e68ff";
    document.getElementById("image").innerHTML = "Hover over an image below to display here.";
}
```

```html
<div id = "image">
    Hover over an image below to display here.
</div>

<img class = "preview"
     alt = "Styling with a Bandana"
     src = "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon.jpg"
     onmouseover = "upDate(this)"
     onmouseout = "unDo()">

<img class = "preview"
     alt = "With My Boy"
     src = "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon2.JPG"
     onmouseover = "upDate(this)"
     onmouseout = "unDo()">

<img class = "preview"
     src = "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon3.jpg"
     alt = "Young Puppy"
     onmouseover = "upDate(this)"
     onmouseout = "unDo()">
```

Answer (score 1):

'previewPic.src' seems to be a variable that has been used as a string. You should replace this piece of code

```
document.getElementById("image").style.backgroundColor = "url(previewPic.src)";
```

with

```
document.getElementById("image").style. backgroundImage = "url('"+previewPic.src+"')";
```

Comment: Good catch. But you can not set `url` to `backgroundColor`. It should be `backgroundImage` instead.

Comment: That is so true. apologies for not correcting it while pasting it back. I will do that right away!

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById("image").style.backgroundColor = "#8e68ff";
```

> Above code is not valid first of all, you need to provide a unique id to your HTML element like -

```
<img class = "preview"
 id="preview1"
 src = "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon3.jpg"
 alt = "Young Puppy"
 onmouseover = "upDate(this)"
 onmouseout = "unDo()">
```

> Now you can access this HTML image element using the id and change its src like this -

```
document.getElementById("preview1").src = "hackanm.gif";
```

> If you are using multiple image elements, please note that you have to use different ids for them.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change below things.

1. `div` should have `backgroundImage` not `backgroundColor`.
2. you have to set `url` this way `"url('" + previewPic.src + "')"`
3. Remove `backgroundImage` in `unDo()` with `document.getElementById("image").style.backgroundImage = "";`

All you need to update is one line like this `document.getElementById("image").style.backgroundImage = "url('" + previewPic.src + "')";`

Check your result below.

```js
function upDate(previewPic){
    // document.getElementById("image").style.backgroundColor = "green";
    document.getElementById("image").style.backgroundImage = "url('" + previewPic.src + "')";
    document.getElementById("image").innerHTML = previewPic.alt + ".  this is onmouseover events";
}

function unDo(){
    document.getElementById("image").style.backgroundImage = "";
    document.getElementById("image").style.backgroundColor = "#8e68ff";
    document.getElementById("image").innerHTML = "Hover over an image below to display here.";
}
```

```html
<div id = "image">
    Hover over an image below to display here.
</div>

<img class = "preview"
     alt = "Styling with a Bandana"
     src = "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon.jpg"
     onmouseover = "upDate(this)"
     onmouseout = "unDo()">

<img class = "preview"
     alt = "With My Boy"
     src = "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon2.JPG"
     onmouseover = "upDate(this)"
     onmouseout = "unDo()">

<img class = "preview"
     src = "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon3.jpg"
     alt = "Young Puppy"
     onmouseover = "upDate(this)"
     onmouseout = "unDo()">
```